# Is it always safe to use C++14's auto function type return deduction in place of std::common_type?

Tags: c++, return, auto, c++14, return-type-deduction

I'm upgrading part of my codebase from C++11 to C++14. I have several math utility functions that take multiple input arguments and return a single value of type `std::common_type_t<...>`.

I'm thinking of replacing the explicit return value with a simple `auto`. I think that type deduction does try to find a common type in these cases. Is there any case where this wouldn't work?

Is it **always safe** to convert all occurrences of `std::common_type_T<...>` return values with `auto`?

Example function:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> 
std::common_type_t<T1, T2, T3> getClamped(T1 mValue, T2 mMin, T3 mMax)
{       
    return mValue < mMin ? mMin : (mValue > mMax ? mMax : mValue);
}
```

Comment: No, but ?: does have a common type.

Comment: Can I ask why you take arguments of different types for a function like this and not just a single type?

Comment: @mattnewport: Probably because it cannot be deduced otherwise. Think `std::min(1, 1.)`. For this particular case it would be better to prevent deduction on min/max, but it doesn't apply in the general case.

Comment: @K-ballo It's not obvious to me where that would be desirable behaviour though, as you say it's not something you really want in the case of min or in the case of the clamp function in the question I wouldn't think.

Comment: @mattnewport, basically what K-ballo said and also there are some functions that use (mathematical) vector types. I usually return `Vector2D<std::common_type_t<...>>` to make sure I return the most general vector type

Comment: What does **safe** mean for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not always safe.

I assume your math functions do more than this, but here is an example where the result will be different.

```
template <class T, class U>
std::common_type_t<T, U> add(T t, U u) { return t + u; }
```

If you call this function with two `char`s the result will be a `char`. Would you auto deduce the return type, it would yield an `int`.

Comment: @Jarod42 It's easy to miss, but he's used `std::common_type_t`, not `std::common_type`. This means you don't need to surround a trait with `typename std::XXX<T>::type`. However, this is only valid in C++14.

Comment: @PhilWright: My comment was before Vittorio's edit. But thanks, now I can delete my obsolete comment.